# Can "around" be used to mean "concerning"?

Tags: word-usage

**Question:** Can *around* be used to mean *concerning*?

**Background:** As an academic editor, I have come across the usage of *around* as in *concerning* or *about* (i.e., having to do with) in numerous PhD dissertations. *Around* in this sense often collocates with *research*, as in the contrived example:

> Research **around** this topic has yet to yield any useful insights.

I haven't been able to find any discussions dealing with this usage, but I have found that:

- non-spacial definitions of *around* do not appear to cover any meaning similar to *concerning* or *about* (in the sense of concerning) (e.g., [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/around?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld))
- existing discussions on the usage of *around* as in *about* deals with meaning similar to *approximately* (e.g., Garner's Modern American Usage)
- This [list of synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/concerning?s=t) for concerning includes *about*, but not *around*.

I'm thinking that because *about* and *around* are interchangeable or vary regionally when used to mean *approximately*, writers transfer this interchangeability to other meanings. In this case, I mean that the meaning of *about* that denotes relevance is being transferred (inappropriately) to *around*.

Because of all this, I have, in every instance, changed *around* to *concerning*, *about*, *on*, etc, but, I'd love confirmation that this is a necessary change. Can anyone point me to any resources that validate this usage of *around*?

Comment: It's easier to understand if you read "around" to mean "in the area of".

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change it. The OED's definition for **around** includes

> 11. In reference or relation to; concerning, about.

This usage is attested back to the late nineteenth century:

> 1897   *Punch* 29 May 263/3   Essence of Parliament... Useful, but not
>   precisely alluring, debate around Employers' Liability Bill.

("around, adv. and prep." Definition B.11. *OED Online*. Oxford University Press, September 2016. Web. 10 September 2016.)

Answer (score 0):

Around is often used that way but your sources seem correct and strictly it seems to me ambiguous.

Research *around* this topic… seems to me to convey *on the periphery* rather than *directly concerning*.

Research *about* might be a little less tenuous.

Research *into* or *on* should be much more clear.

Answer (score -1):

I have heard this primarily used by businesspeople, beginning in early 2007; it therefore has always sounded like pretentious business jargon to me. There are certainly better words: regarding, concerning, related to, etc. The intended word often seems to be "surrounding."

Comment: Yeah, definitely Un-American:  *For both these reasons, discussions around the resolution demand flesh thinking.*  [1967](https://books.google.com/books?id=YGBbAAAAcAAJ&q=%22discussions+around%22&dq=%22discussions+around%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv3sny6o7UAhVs6oMKHfvLBME4FBDoAQgxMAM)

Comment: Maybe the users are thinking of "dancing around an issue", and thus "research around" with the same focus.