# Debates about vs debates around

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> I am familiar with all the debates **around/about** this topic.

Are both ‘around’ and ‘about’ equally good in the above context? Do they both mean the same thing?

Comment: [Related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347553/can-around-be-used-to-mean-concerning) to which Robbie Goodwin's answer appears to be directly relevant.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Another comment there says that OED’s validate using around in the sense of concerning.

Comment: So are you happy that since *about* and *around* both mean "concerning" that this question is a duplicate of that one?

Comment: To me a debate about a topic is more focused than a debate around a topic.

Comment: Everyone seems to be forgetting debates **over** this topic.

Comment: @AndrewLeach First, why should I by happy? Is that a particular usage for ‘happy’ here? Second, I can ask also about “concerning vs. about’’. So, no, I don’t believe this is a dubplicate question of that one. And, the fact that people like you closed the question so quick shows there is a problem in this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with *about* — at least in more formal situations.

A search of  the Corpus of Contemporary American English shows the frequency of [*debate around*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=99944711) at 142 compared to [*debate about*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=99944720) at 4356.

[Google Books Ngram Viewer offers similar results.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=debate+about%2Cdebate+around&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdebate%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdebate%20around%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdebate%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdebate%20around%3B%2Cc0)

Although the *Oxford English Dictionary* shows a few example usages for *around* in the sense of *concerning* (the first at 1897), it seems to me (and to [this writer](https://slate.com/human-interest/2014/07/about-around-surrounding-prepositions-shifting-to-have-similar-meanings.html)) that this usage has only relatively recently gained traction.

Lastly, I would have you look at *debate* the verb and then make your decision:

> *We debated about this topic. There was a debate about this topic.*
>
> *We debated around this topic. There was a debate around this topic.*

For precision’s sake, I would use *around* only where *surrounding* makes sense:

> *I am familiar with all the issues surrounding this topic.*
>
> *I am familiar with all the issues around this topic.*